# Emitter not rendering, but particles are. Not restricted, and emitter option ticked in particle system

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Working in 2.79, I'm attempting to work on a grassy field, may extend to a larger background piece later, but currently I hit a wall in production. After many troubles texturing my particle system, I gave everything a material and rendered, but no matter what I do, my plane doesn't render, just the particles.

I've even attempted duplicating the plane and removing the particle system from the duplicate to just have it sitting beneath it, but that doesn't work.

I've changed materials to one I know isn't transparent, so it isn't a problem with the material, and I can't, for the life of me, find anything in object, material, or render options that can fix it.

Edit: I started with a simple plane and subdivided, fractal'd, etc. to get the shape I wanted. I went through making four different sets of grass clumps for my particle system and set it to pick randomly from that set, and gave it a cloud texture for good dispersal of the particles.

My settings, limited to relevance, are attached in images, if all works correctly...

[image: Here, my settings.]

Despite this, below is an attached image depicting what I get in render. Notice my brown material for the plane doesn't show up. I made the background transparent in order to make it clear that my plane just... isn't there.

[image: No plane]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project and the particles. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Editted, hopefully this is more clear now.

Comment: Welp... I feel dumb. I just found that my Shadow Catcher option was on, and that was what caused it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that was the answer indeed, why turn it into a comment?

Comment: Well it felt unsubstantial and read more like a comment than a full answer, but I can reinstate. It also has a downvote so it might need some love

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yet another case of the [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @cegaton Indeed. Undeleted, do upvote so the user doesn't get a rep penalty

Answer (score 2):

I just found that it was not related to particles but a completely different setting. The *Shadow Catcher* option that was turned on on the plane, and that was what caused it.